# Using Enums instead of Hardcoded value

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have some code that detects which tab is selected in a `QListWidget`

```
int currentTab=ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();

if (currentTab==0)
     {
     // Code here
     }
else if (currentTab==1)
     {
    // Code here
     }
else if (currentTab==2)
     {
     // code here
     }
else if (currentTab==3)
     {
   // code here
     }
```

How do i use Enums instead of `if(currentTab==0)` or `if(currentTab==1)` or `if(currentTab==2)` or `if(currentTab==3)`

Comment: Why? currentIndex is an index.

Comment: You should look into `switch()` for this. Enums just make hard coded values easier to understand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would handle the same in the following way (with using an enum type):

```
enum Tabs {
    Tab1,
    Tab2,
    Tab3
};

void foo()
{
    int currentTab = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
    switch (currentTab) {
    case Tab1:
        // Handle the case
        break;
    case Tab2:
        // Handle the case
        break;
    case Tab3:
        // Handle the case
        break;
    default:
        // Handle all the rest cases.
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `default` required by the compiler when you describe all the possible values in cases ?

Comment: In some it is: you can add `Q_UNREACHABLE()` in there, this way the compiler assumes this place will never be reached. (And in debug mode it will assert if it does)

Comment: It is not required, but having it in the `switch` statement is a good idea for handling default values and/or cases, when `currentTab > 2` in my example. Some compilers can report a warning if you miss it.

Answer (score 0):

Example to use the Enums given below.
if you want to use same enum element in two enumerations, then you can use the [enum classes (strongly typed enumerations) **C++11**](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

//enumeration with type and size
enum class employee_tab : std::int8_t {
    first=0 /*default*/, second, third, last /*last tab*/
};

enum class employee_test : std::int16_t {
    first=10 /*start value*/, second, third, last /*last tab*/
};

enum class employee_name : char {
    first='F', middle='M', last='L'
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    //int currentTab=ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
    employee_tab currentTab = (employee_tab)1;
    switch (currentTab) {
        case employee_tab::first: //element with same name
            cout << "First tab Selected" << endl;
            break;
        case employee_tab::second:
            cout << "Second tab Selected" << endl;
            break;
        case employee_tab::third:
            cout << "Third tab Selected" << endl;
            break;
        case employee_tab::last: //element with same name
            cout << "Fourth tab Selected" << endl;
            break;
    }

    employee_name currentName = (employee_name)'F';
    switch (currentName) {
        case employee_name::first: //element with same name
            cout << "First Name Selected" << endl;
            break;
        case employee_name::middle:
            cout << "Middle Name Selected" << endl;
            break;
        case employee_name::last: //element with same name
            cout << "Last Name Selected" << endl;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**
Second tab Selected
First Name Selected